# Lyx - side-by-side figure inside two-column layoutt

Tags: lyx, two-column

I have created side-by-side images in Lyx using this [link](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/FiguresSideBySide)

It works just fine in 1-column article. But If I switch to two columns, images started to overflow page. I have set image scale for each of the images separately.

How to use images in two columns to be aligned, or some of them to be space across two columns?

I need this solution inside Lyx, so conversion into Tex and then modify Tex is not possible.

Comment: The first part (two pictures in one column) seems to work for me. Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: related email thread (and possible solution) on lyx-users: https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg101760.html

Comment: To make a float span the two columns, right click *float: figure*, choose Settings, and check the box for *Span columns*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. *Insert > Float > Figure*.
2. Inside float figure: *Insert > Box > Frameless*.
3. Inside Frameless: Add your first image, then *Insert > Caption* to add the caption.
4. Inside float figure (but outside the first frameless box): *Insert > Box > Frameless*.
5. Inside frameless: Add your second image, then *Insert > Caption* to add the caption.
6. Right click on the frameless box, choose frameless option then make the width under 50%, like 40%.
7. If you make the width of frameless1 and frameless2 like 40,40% i think you solved your problem.

Regards

Comment: Forgive me, my edit and (now deleted) comment was a bit arrogant. I didn't realize that LyX automatically adds subfloats when adding figures within figure. Edit: Do roll back your answer to the original version if you prefer that.